# bash script adding ' ' to variables with curl

Tags: bash, curl

I have a simple bash script that uses an api to add itself into a database. But the script keeps adding ' ' to my variables and its breaking curl.

```
hostname=`hostname`
ip_address=`ip add show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -d '/' -f1`
env=`hostname | cut -d '-' -f1`
os=`cat /etc/issue.net | head -1`
date=`date`
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -PUT "https://10.10.10.10/database" -k -d '{"Environment":"'$env'","Hostname":"'$hostname'","IP_Address":"'$ip_address'","OS":"'$os'","State":"OK","Updated_Time":"'$date'"}'
exit $?
```

The output is this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -PUT https://10.10.10.10/database -k -d '{"Environment":"ops","Hostname":"ex-example-host","IP_Address":"10.10.10.10","OS":"Ubuntu' 14.04 'LTS","State":"OK","Updated_Time":"Thu' Aug 14 15:27:55 PDT '2014"}'
```

Both the `$date` and `$hostname` put ' ' on the inside the format breaking the curl. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: When you say "the output", I think you mean what you see when you enable `set -x`. That's not what the application sees. `set -x` shows you what you could type directly to achieve the same effect. So the quotes that it shows are (in this case) not passed to `curl`. @chepner's answer is correct, although you could also achieve the same effect by double-quoting the variable interpolations: `..."'"$date"'"...` or by double-quoting the whole `-d` argument and backslash-escaping the double-quotes which you want to pass through.

Comment: @rici I tried the `"'"` and that did not work. Still did the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are leaving the parameter expansions unquoted in `bash`, so spaces in those values break up the word being passed to `curl`. It would be simpler to swap your use of double and single quotes, if JSON allowed you to use single quotes. That not being the case, I'd store the JSON in a variable using `read` and a here document first to simplify the quoting.

```
read -r data <<EOF
{"Environment":"$env","Hostname":"$hostname","IP_Address":"$ip_address","OS":"$os","State":"OK","Updated_Time":"$date"}
EOF

curl ... -d "$data"
```